# Checking for missing values in several columns of a spreadsheet

Tags: vba, excel

Basically I had 3 columns of Data

1. Adjudicated Cases
2. Not Adjudicated Cases
3. All Cases

and I wanted to get a list of all the cases that were missing from Column A and Column B, with a little help from @RubberDucky and his really cool Enumerable.cls (Found on [GitHub in His VBX Repository](https://github.com/ckuhn203/VBEX/blob/master/Core/Enumerable.cls)) I used the Merge function to first merge Column A and Column B together in an Enumerable and then using the Contains function I checked to see if the Values in the Enumerable were contained in Column C, if they weren't there I added them to a second Enumerable and then printed that one out into another column.

How can I further hone my VBA skills?

```
Sub FindUnAssigned()
    With Sheets("FY13")
        Dim e As New Enumerable
        Dim lastARow As Integer
        lastARow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Dim lastBRow As Integer
        lastBRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        Set e.Collection = Range("A3:A" & lastARow)
        e.Merge (Range("B3:B" & lastBRow))

        Dim cell As Range
        Dim columnD As New Enumerable
        Dim lastCRow As Integer
        lastCRow = .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For Each cell In Range("C3:C" & lastCRow)
            If Not (e.Contains(cell.value, True)) Then
                columnD.Add (cell.value)
            End If
        Next cell

        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 1 To columnD.Count
            Dim j As Integer
            j = i + 2
            Range(("D" & j), ("D" & columnD.Count + 2)) = columnD.item(i)
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- I discourage the use of single letter variable names. So, I recommend changing `e` to something else. I'm drawing a blank though because you can't use `Cells` in Excel's flavor of [vba](/questions/tagged/vba). That's the object that refers to the sheet's collection of all cells. Maybe `cases` would work given the context.
- I like your use of the `With` statement here. I'm tossing that out there because I know others will disagree with me. `With` can be abused, but this is not the case with your code.
- When declaring an iterator variable for a `ForEach` statement, I like to declare it just outside the loop. You should move `Dim cell As Range`.
- `j` is a useless variable. I would just add two to `i` instead.
- Speaking of `2`, it's a magic number. I would consider declaring an `offset` variable.

  ```
      Dim i As Integer
      Const offset As Integer = 2

      For i = 1 To columnD.Count
          Range(("D" & i + offset), ("D" & columnD.Count + offset)) = columnD.item(i)
      Next i
  ```
- I take back what I said about the `With` statement. It would be a good use, but you're using `Range` wrong. For example, this line doesn't do what you think it does.

  > ```
  > Range(("D" & i + offset), ("D" & columnD.Count + offset))
  > ```

  You're using the ***global*** Range object, which is the same as saying `ActiveSheet.Range()`. That's not what you want. This can lead to some hard to track down heisenbugs. You want to work on your named sheet. You need to add the dot in order to be working on the named sheet.

  ```
  .Range(("D" & i + offset), ("D" & columnD.Count + offset))
  ```

---

From here on out I'm at a bit of an unfair advantage because I wrote the `Enumerable` class that you're using.

- You don't need the `.value` when using the `useDefaultProperty` option. `Value` is the default property of any `Range` object.

  > ```
  > If Not (e.Contains(cell.value, True)) Then
  > ```

  Can be changed to

  ```
  If Not (e.Contains(cell, True)) Then
  ```
- The same thing applies to the `Add` method.

  > ```
  > columnD.Add (cell.value)
  > ```
- `Enumerable` uses a magic attribute that gives it a default property as well. So, just like the built in `Collection`, there's no reason to use the verbose method of getting an item. `Item` is the default property.

  > ```
  > columnD.item(i)
  > ```

  Becomes

  ```
  columnD(i)
  ```

Comment: @Malachi I updated my answer. There was a subtle bug with the use of `Range`.

Answer (score 4):

@RubberDuck hits some good points, so I'll just mention another couple things with the original code.

First, your last row variables shouldn't be `Integer` variables.  Excel can return values for row counts that overflow them.  Get into the habit of using `Long` variables instead.  This might not be an issue with your particular use case, but it will be at some point so the sooner you get in that habit the better.

Second. Avoid `String` concats in loops whenever possible.  VBA is no different than any other language in that string operations are expensive.  Likewise, avoid using methods such as `.Count` that return the same value in every loop iteration.  Don't forget - this is a function call.  Cache it instead. For example, in this loop:

```
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To columnD.Count
        Dim j As Integer
        j = i + 2
        Range(("D" & j), ("D" & columnD.Count + 2)) = columnD.item(i)
    Next i
```

No reason to use the `Range` object when you are selecting single cells.  Use `.Cells` instead so you skip the concat.

```
    Const offset As Integer = 2
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To columnD.Count
        .Cells(i + offset, 4).Value = columnD(i)
    Next i
```

Third, turning off screen updating is your friend if you are going to be writing values to a lot of cells.  Again, I don't know the use case here, but it is a good habit to get into especially because of...

Finally, performance.  There are some things that VBA does well, but in general the built in Excel functions are going to be much, much better *regardless* of your algorithm.  I have yet to find a function that I can outperform Excel with if a native alternative exists. First among those functions are look-ups and sorting, which Excel does extremely well.  I took the liberty of testing your code with the numbers 1 through 10,000 in D3:D10003, 5000 random numbers between 1 and 10000 in column A, and 3000 of the same in column B.  Your code took about a minute and a half to execute (in my resource starved VM).  The code below took 10 seconds:

```
Sub FindUnAssignedFaster()

    Const top As Integer = 3
    Dim bottom As Long
    bottom = Sheets("FY13").Cells(Rows.Count, top).End(xlUp).Row

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Apply the following formula to the output range (assuming 3 is top and 10002 is bottom):
    '=IF(AND(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(C3,$A$3:$A$10002,1,FALSE)=C3),ISERROR(VLOOKUP(C3,$B$3:$B$10002,1,FALSE)=C3)),C3,"")

    With Range("D" & top & ":D" & bottom)
        .Formula = "=IF(AND(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(C" & top & ",$A$" & top & ":$A$" & bottom & _
                   ",1,FALSE)=C" & top & ")," & "ISERROR(VLOOKUP(C" & top & ",$B$" & top & _
                   ":$B$" & bottom & ",1,FALSE)=C" & top & ")),C" & top & ","""")"
        .Value = .Value
        .SortSpecial
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

While this admittedly suffers in readability, it slays in performance.  Don't take this as an indictment of your code (which is well thought out and written) as much as a warning against trying to beat Excel at its own game with VBA.

Comment: Very good advice. Native Excel is always faster. ++ I don't know if you chat on SE, but we started a [Code Review VBA chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14929/vba).